# In plain English what is the difference between a most powerful test and a uniformly most powerful test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, neyman-pearson-lemma

I'm having trouble understanding the two concepts of a powerful test and a uniformly powerful test. I'm reading about these tests in context of the Neyman Pearson Lemma and it seems like they're virtually the same thing?

Comment: It is the difference from being most powerful against a fixed alternative and most against the set of all possible alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

"Uniformly" means regardless of the values of the unobservable parameters. One test may be the most powerful one for a particular value of an unobservable parameter while a different test is the most powerful one for a different value of the parameter. A uniformly more powerful test remains the most powerful one regardless of the value of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

According to Mood [1]

- Most powerful test (MP): a test $\delta$ of $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta = \theta_1$ of *size* $\alpha$ is MP if it has the greatest power $\pi(\theta_1 \mid \delta)$ among all tests of size $\alpha$ or less, where $\pi$ is the power function. In words, $\delta$ has the greatest capacity of detecting $H_1$ among tests of *size at most* $\alpha$ and these specific hypothesis.
- Uniformly most powerful test (UMP): a test $\delta$ of $H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta \in \Theta - \Theta_0$ *size* $\alpha$ is UMP if it has the greatest power $\pi_{\theta \in \Theta_1}(\theta \mid \delta)$ among all tests of size $\alpha$ *or less*. "Uniformly" refers to all values of $\theta$.

Notice the difference in the two staments with respect to the hypothesis and power. A *non-UMP* test can be *most powerful just for a specific value* of $\theta$. A UMP test is is the "most powerful" test for each value of $\theta$ in $H_1$.

[1] Mood, Alexander McFarlane. "Introduction to the Theory of Statistics." (1950).